# Keeping Excluded Values in ArcMap Layers

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy, arcmap

I wrote a model using Model Builder to create a Raster layer and import symbology from a saved Raster Layer.  But when I run it, the excluded value of 0 appears on the resulting layer, and the display was resampled using Nearest Neighbor rather than Bilinear Interpolation, as in the saved Raster Layer.  Does anyone know why this happens, and how to get around this?  Is there a way to set all the layer properties solely using Python?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Setting all of the properties you want can be done when you first create the raster dataset that you want to use as the input layer file.

This link lists the properties you can set: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Create_Raster_Dataset/001700000096000000/.

The pyramid optional argument is where you can tell it to resample using Bilinear interpolation. You can then create the raster layer from from this dataset and it will have the properties you wanted.